# SNMP closed state in CentOS

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, snmp

I'm having a problem here, I've added to my IPtables rules this:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
```

but when I scan with nmap or any other tool it says this:

```
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
161/tcp closed snmp
```

also when I am doing:

```
netstat -apn | grep snmpd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:199               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3669/snmpd<br>
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:161                 0.0.0.0:*                               3669/snmpd<br>
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    226186 3669/snmpd
```

Also:

```
service iptables status

Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:161
5    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:161
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
7    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any idea what's going on? There is no UDP in closed/open state. what do I have to do?

Comment: What `nmap` command did you use?  Did you have the `-sU` option set?

Comment: Ladadadada is right. But probably you are working with a wrong community, this is why doesn't work.

Comment: I am using the nmap -sT -O IP_ADDR but with nmap -sU -O IP_ADDR i don't take any response for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `snmpd` listens to UDP port 161 on all interfaces.  If you want to use TCP, you will have to configure that in your `snmpd.conf` or in `/etc/default/snmpd`.

The fact that `nmap` sees port 161 as "closed" rather than "filtered" means that it got a `RST` packet in return when it tried to contact TCP port 161 rather than getting nothing back.  This means that your IPTables rules are working fine.

Comment: Also i've removed the ip table rule for TCP and i leaved only the UDP rule. Now it doesn't response at all.